# Disable scrolling in iframe with a typeform

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, typeform

I have a typeform form embedded in an iframe but I don't want it to scroll within the iframe itself.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe class="typeform-widget"
      src="https://weblify.typeform.com/to/WDbDw2" data-transparency="50"
      data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
    </iframe>
    <script> 
    (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Do you mean that the typeform page has height more than that of iframe and now it behaves like overflow: auto while you want it behave like overflow: hidden? Or you want iframe to have enough height to prevent the scrollbar to appear?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you really need to use an `iframe` element, maybe it's because of your context.

From [Typeform's embed SDK](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/) and one of their [examples](https://codepen.io/Typeform/pen/rzaMEB) I see that they use a `div` with `id="my-embedded-typeform"` and then they load the embed SDK script and a custom script to configure and trigger it.

```
    <div id="my-embedded-typeform"
     style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>



    <script src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js" type="text/javascript">`enter code here`</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var el = document.getElementById("my-embedded-typeform");

      // When instantiating a widget embed, you must provide the DOM element
      // that will contain your typeform, the URL of your typeform, and your
      // desired embed settings
      window.typeformEmbed.makeWidget(el, "https://admin.typeform.com/to/cVa5IG", {
        hideFooter: true,
        hideHeaders: true,
        opacity: 0
      });
    });
  </script>
```

They [mention](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/custom-embed/) in their docs that custom scripts for embedding are not recommended as they may cause scrolling issues (amongst other things).

Maybe following [their guides](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/modes/) could help your purposes or at least make it more manageable.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
.typeform-widget:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    left: 94%;
}
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work.. I still can scroll within the iframe itself

Comment: mm u tryied to add <iframe src="" scrolling="no"> ? and  style="overflow:hidden;" ?